# How to define cross entropy for equal logits and labels?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

So basically we usually define cross entropy like this:

```
dim = 5



logits = tf.random_normal([5,3],dtype=tf.float32)

labels = tf.cast(tf.one_hot(10,5),tf.int32)

cost_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=labels)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    a,b=sess.run([logits,labels])
    print(b)
    print(sess.run(cost_entropy))
    print('\n')
    print(a)
```

output:

```
[0 0 0 0 0]
[1.8559302 2.1816468 2.9526126 1.5903687 2.500083 ]


[[ 0.1913337   0.32995617 -0.23624638]
 [ 0.65993434 -0.2852072  -1.1419022 ]
 [-0.2529132  -0.35611948  0.4710417 ]
 [-0.61094457 -0.76033163 -0.6311429 ]
 [-1.5868235   0.81744194 -0.31859735]]
```

Now if my logits are :

```
[[ 0.1913337   0.32995617 -0.23624638]
 [ 0.65993434 -0.2852072  -1.1419022 ]
 [-0.2529132  -0.35611948  0.4710417 ]
 [-0.61094457 -0.76033163 -0.6311429 ]
 [-1.5868235   0.81744194 -0.31859735]]
```

And my labels are same shape of logits like :

```
[ [ 0     1   0]
  [ 1     0   1]
  [1      1   0]
  [1      1   1]
  [0      0   0] ]
```

So each value in logits have a 0 or one ( One hot encoding ) , How can i achieve that ? I tried with

```
 `tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`
```

and

```
`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`
```

But it's giving Error .

For more explanation :

So suppose my input is . `[ [12 , 14 , 15 ] . , [23 ,24 , 25 ] ]` . now i will get logits for this input like . `[ [ 0.11 , -0.1 , 0.2 ] , [0.91 0.2 0.12] ]` . now my labels are for this logits . `[ [ 0, 0 , 1 ] , [ 1 , 0 ,1 ] ]` . it means i want . `[0.2]` from first and `[0.91 , 0.12]` from second

from this vector `[ 0.11 , -0.1 , 0.2 ]` . i wan last one so my label are `[ 0 , 0 ,1 ]` 
from this vector `[0.91 0.2 0.12]` . i want first and last so i want `[ 1, 0, 1]`

Comment: your labels have several ones per row, do you intend to do multi-label classification?

Comment: @ted yes it's kind of multi label but here input is itself logit (in one hot encoded ) , so those 0 means i don't want that in logits and one means i want that.

Comment: unclear. please provide an example where the code fails please

Comment: @ted Simple example would be suppose my input is [2,4] and my logits is also [2,4] one hot , Now i want to create cross entropy function for this two .

Comment: what do you call "input"? cross entropy expects `logits` and `labels`. Do you mean you have `[2, 4]` as labels and `[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]` as `logits` (which would give you a loss of `0`)

Comment: @ted my labels and logits looks like same as i describe above , there logits shape is [5,3]   and labels shape is also [5,3 ] (one hot )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174719/discussion-between-ayodhyankit-paul-and-ted).

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand. What do you mean by "wanting" those logits? Are you looking for `tf.boolean_mask`?

Comment: @xdurch0 i tried to describe , Please see the last part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're looking for multilabel classification. Here is a working example:

```
dim = 5

tf.reset_default_graph()

logits = tf.random_normal([2,3],dtype=tf.float32)

labels = tf.Variable([[ 0 , 0 ,1 ], [ 1, 0, 1]], dtype=tf.float32)

cost_entropy = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits,labels=labels)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.reduce_mean(cost_entropy, axis=0))


with tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
    print(sess.run(cost_entropy))
    print(sess.run(loss))
```

which prints

```
[[0.68918824 1.1838193  0.40476277]
[1.5736797  0.6862114  0.9196656 ]]
2.4358916
```